# Needing help trying to Format DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, junit, shopify, datetimeoffset

So for my assignemtn,I am instructed to create unit tests for Shopify integration. One of my assert methods require me to format the date a certain way.

My assert method is this and the following trace is as follows. It's really difficult trying to keep up with the documentations.

```
assertEquals((new Date(2020, 7, 23)),order.getCreatedAt());

java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<Mon Aug 23 00:00:00 EDT 3920> but was:<2020-07-23T11:47:45.000-04:00>
```

Comment: you need to truncate the date object and get ride of time portion if you only need to compare date part

Comment: Use `java.time.LocalDate` and **stop using `java.util.Date`**, please

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util.Date` to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

## What went wrong with your code:

`java.util.Date` considers the first month as `0` which means `7` stands for `August` with it. Also, it adds `1900` to the parameter, `year` which means that for `2020` as the value of this parameter, it will give you an object with the year set as `3920`. I hope, this is enough to understand how horribly `java.util.Date` has been designed.

## Using the modern date-time API:

You can do it as follows:

```
OffsetDateTime testData = OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(2020, Month.JULY, 23, 11, 47, 45, 0),
                ZoneOffset.ofHours(-4));
assertEquals(testData, order.getCreatedAt());
```

This is based on the assumption that `order.getCreatedAt()` returns an object of `OffsetDateTime`. Note that you can use, `7` instead of `Month.JULY` but the later is the idiomatic way of expressing the value of the month.

If `order.getCreatedAt()` returns `2020-07-23T11:47:45.000-04:00` as `String`, you can parse it to `OffsetDateTime` as shown below:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Parse the given date-time string to OffsetDateTime
        OffsetDateTime orderCreatedAt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-07-23T11:47:45.000-04:00");

        // Create test data
        OffsetDateTime testData = OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(2020, Month.JULY, 23, 11, 47, 45, 0),
                ZoneOffset.ofHours(-4));

        // Display
        System.out.println(orderCreatedAt);
        System.out.println(testData);

        // Assert
        //assertEquals(testData, orderCreatedAt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-07-23T11:47:45-04:00
2020-07-23T11:47:45-04:00
```

Learn more about modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.